# A problem regarding functional analysis and Riesz's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a subspace of the real space $C[0,1]$ consisting of all continuous functions $x$ on $[0,1]$ such that $x(0)=0$. For $X_0$ we take the subspace of all $x\in X$ such that $\int\limits_0^1 x(t) dt=0$. Now suppose that $x_1\in X$, $||x_1||=1$, and $||x_1-x||\geq 1$ if $x\in X_0$. Corresponding to each $y\in X\backslash X_0$, we let

$$c=\frac{\int\limits_0^1 x_1(t)dt}{\int\limits_0^1 y(t)dt}$$

Then

$$x_1-cy\in X_0$$.

How does this last line come about?

It's part of an example from the Functional Analysis text by Taylor.

Comment: $\int\limits_0^1 \left(x_1-cy\right)dt = \int\limits_0^1 x_1dt - c\int\limits_0^1ydt = \int\limits_0^1x_1dt - \int\limits_0^1x_1dt=0$

Comment: The point of this exercise: Let $X$ be a normed real vector space.Let $f:X\to \Bbb R$ be linear and  let there exist $K\in \Bbb R$  such that $|f(x)|\leq K\|x\|$ for all $x\in X.$  If $f\ne 0$ then $f^{-1}\{0\} $ has co-dimension 1 in X, which means there exists  $x_1\in X\setminus f^{-1}\{0\}$... (...any $x_1 \in X \setminus f^{-1}\{0\}$ will do...) ...such that the vector space generated by $\{x_1\}\cup f^{-1}\{0\}$ is all of $X$..... Here, $\|x\|=\sup \{|x(t)|: t\in [0,1]\}$ and $f(x)=\int_0^1x(t)dt$ and $K=1$.